# i have developed an one to one chat app in android .if i killed an app then i don't get notification. how to solve that programmatic

Tags: android

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){

   Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);

 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

 context.startActivity(i);

   }


 }


}
```

Comment: how you are getting notification on device ?

Comment: what's your mobile name and android version???

Comment: i am using Firebase @TejasPandya,Vivo mobile and version android 7

Comment: do you have any backend to trigger notification from server ?

Comment: i didn't get that @ Tejas Pandya as a iam new to android ..

Comment: public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {